# Restarting a while loop from the beginning / java

Tags: java

I have a game of tic tac toe that I need to play all the way through and then ask the user if they would like to play again.

I'm not sure how I would go about clearing the array and starting from the beginning of the loop.

I have a method at the very bottom of the code that I was thinking would possibly work but haven't had much luck with it.

Any help would be amazing thanks!

```
public class TicTacToe {

    public static char[][] board = new char[3][3];
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static String keepPlaying;
    public static char yesOrNo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        User human1 = new User();
        User human2 = new User();

        human1.getUser1Name();
        human2.getUser2Name();

        System.out.println("\nPlayer 1: " + human1.human1Name() + ": X's");
        System.out.println("Player 2: " + human2.human2Name() + ": O's\n");

        initializeBoard();
        displayBoard();

        boolean playing = true;

        while (playing) {
            System.out.println("\n" + human1.human1Name() + " it's your turn.");
            human1.getChoice();
            human1.convert();

            if (human1.returnRow() == 0 && human1.returnCol() == 0 && board[0][0] == ' ') {
                board[0][0] = 'X';
                displayBoard();
            } else if (human1.returnRow() == 0 && human1.returnCol() == 1 && board[1][0] == ' ') {
                board[1][0] = 'X';
                displayBoard();
            } else if (human1.returnRow() == 0 && human1.returnCol() == 2 && board[2][0] == ' ') {
                board[2][0] = 'X';
                displayBoard();
            } else if (human1.returnRow() == 1 && human1.returnCol() == 0 && board[0][1] == ' ') {
                board[0][1] = 'X';
                displayBoard();
            } else if (human1.returnRow() == 1 && human1.returnCol() == 1 && board[1][1] == ' ') {
                board[1][1] = 'X';
                displayBoard();
            } else if (human1.returnRow() == 1 && human1.returnCol() == 2 && board[2][1] == ' ') {
                board[2][1] = 'X';
                displayBoard();
            } else if (human1.returnRow() == 2 && human1.returnCol() == 0 && board[0][2] == ' ') {
                board[0][2] = 'X';
                displayBoard();
            } else if (human1.returnRow() == 2 && human1.returnCol() == 1 && board[1][2] == ' ') {
                board[1][2] = 'X';
                displayBoard();
            } else if (human1.returnRow() == 2 && human1.returnCol() == 2 && board[2][2] == ' ') {
                board[2][2] = 'X';
                displayBoard();
            }

            checkForWinner();

            if (checkForWinner() == true) {
                System.out.println("\n" + human1.human1Name() + " has won the game!!!");
                break;
            }

            if (board[0][0] != ' ' && board[0][1] != ' ' && board[0][2] != ' ' && board[1][0] != ' '
                    && board[1][1] != ' ' && board[1][2] != ' ' && board[2][0] != ' ' && board[2][1] != ' '
                    && board[2][2] != ' ') {
                System.out.println("It's a draw!!!");
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("\n" + human2.human2Name() + " it's your turn.");
            human2.getChoice();
            human2.convert();

            if (human2.returnRow() == 0 && human2.returnCol() == 0/* && board[0][0] == ' ' */) {
                if (board[0][0] != ' ') {
                    System.out.println("\n" + human2.human2Name() + " that spot is already taken.");
                    human2.getChoice();
                    human2.convert();

                    continue;
                }
                board[0][0] = 'O';
                displayBoard();
            } else if (human2.returnRow() == 0 && human2.returnCol() == 1 && board[1][0] == ' ') {
                board[1][0] = 'O';
                displayBoard();
            } else if (human2.returnRow() == 0 && human2.returnCol() == 2 && board[2][0] == ' ') {
                board[2][0] = 'O';
                displayBoard();
            } else if (human2.returnRow() == 1 && human2.returnCol() == 0 && board[0][1] == ' ') {
                board[0][1] = 'O';
                displayBoard();
            } else if (human2.returnRow() == 1 && human2.returnCol() == 1 && board[1][1] == ' ') {
                board[1][1] = 'O';
                displayBoard();
            } else if (human2.returnRow() == 1 && human2.returnCol() == 2 && board[2][1] == ' ') {
                board[2][1] = 'O';
                displayBoard();
            } else if (human2.returnRow() == 2 && human2.returnCol() == 0 && board[0][2] == ' ') {
                board[0][2] = 'O';
                displayBoard();
            } else if (human2.returnRow() == 2 && human2.returnCol() == 1 && board[1][2] == ' ') {
                board[1][2] = 'O';
                displayBoard();
            } else if (human2.returnRow() == 2 && human2.returnCol() == 2 && board[2][2] == ' ') {
                board[2][2] = 'O';
                displayBoard();
            }

            checkForWinner();

            if (checkForWinner() == true) {
                System.out.println("\n" + human2.human2Name() + " has won the game!!!");
                break;
            }

            if (board[0][0] != ' ' && board[0][1] != ' ' && board[0][2] != ' ' && board[1][0] != ' '
                    && board[1][1] != ' ' && board[1][2] != ' ' && board[2][0] != ' ' && board[2][1] != ' '
                    && board[2][2] != ' ') {
                System.out.println("It's a draw!!!");
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    public TicTacToe() {

        board = new char[3][3];

    }

    public static void initializeBoard() {

        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                board[row][col] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }

    public static void displayBoard() {

        System.out.println("    A   B   C");
        System.out.println("  -------------");

        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            System.out.print((row + 1) + " | ");
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                System.out.print(board[row][col] + " | ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("  -------------");
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkForWinner() {

        if (board[0][0] == board[0][1] && board[0][1] == board[0][2] && board[0][1] != ' ') {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[1][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[1][2] && board[1][1] != ' ') {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[2][0] == board[2][1] && board[2][1] == board[2][2] && board[2][1] != ' ') {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[0][0] == board[1][0] && board[1][0] == board[2][0] && board[1][0] != ' ') {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[0][1] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][1] && board[1][1] != ' ') {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[0][2] == board[1][2] && board[1][2] == board[2][2] && board[1][2] != ' ') {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2] && board[1][1] != ' ') {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0] && board[1][1] != ' ') {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static boolean playAgain() {

        System.out.println("\nWould you like to play again?");

        keepPlaying = scan.nextLine();

        yesOrNo = keepPlaying.toUpperCase().charAt(0);

        if (yesOrNo == 'N') {
            return false;
        } else if (yesOrNo == 'Y') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a `playAgain` method which is never used, and a boolean `playing` which is always true and is never updated anywhere.

Comment: In addition to previous comments, you also use break to exit the loop in numerous places. Your main method is doing way too much. If you refactored your code to be object-oriented, you would simply create a new instance of a the game object each time someone wanted to keep playing.

Comment: the playAgain method isn't used because it will ask the user if they want the play again but won't do anything and I have tried changing the boolean playing to false but I need it to complete the loop until the game is finished and then start over again from the beginning if the user chooses to do so

Comment: You call `checkForWinner 4 times in your loop so you would want to reduce that to 2 or preferable 1 calls but it is when that method returns true that you should call `playAgain` and if it returns true then call `initializeBoard`, you probably need to do more stuff but this should get you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks Jason, I'm fairly new to programming. This is my first year in computer science and still trying to learn.

Comment: Thank you Joakim!! its working now :) now I just need to figure out how to let the player have another turn if they choose a spot that's already taken.